# Haskell quicksort but for tupple second element without using map, sortby or anything higher order or anything that import is needed for

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, quicksort

I've found this code on the internet for quicksort and I want to modify it to work for the second element of the tuple:

```
sortfreq []=[]
sortfreq (x:xs) =  sortfreq [y | y <- xs, y <= x] ++ [x] ++ sortfreq [y | y <- xs, y > x]
```

I tried doing this modification to the code but this results in sorting by 1st element of the tuple, what do I need to do in order to make it for the second element and why.

```
sortfreq ((a,b):xs) =  sortfreq [y | y <- xs, y <= (a,b)] ++ [(a,b)] ++ sortfreq [y | y <- xs, y > (a,b)]
```

Answer (score 3):

We first need to understand the original code before we can try to modify it:

```hs
-- an empty list, when sorted, is an empty list
sortfreq [] = []
sortfreq (x:xs) =
    -- we sort just the elements less than or equal to the pivot
    sortfreq [y | y <- xs, y <= x]
    -- we choose the first element as our pivot and put it in the middle
    ++ [x]
    -- we sort elements greater than the pivot
    ++ sortfreq [y | y <- xs, y > x]
```

This is the standard quicksort element. Now, if we want to sort based on the first element, we should only compare on the first element:

```hs
sortfreq [] = []
sortfreq (x:xs) =
    -- sort just the elements less than or equal to the pivot's first element
    sortfreq [y | y <- xs, fst y <= fst x]
    -- now the pivot
    ++ [x]
    -- now the ones greater than the pivot
    ++ sortfreq [y | y <- xs, fst y > fst x]
```

As with many custom comparisons, you compare parts of the value, but you move the values as a whole.